# pyspark remove empty values from all columns and replace it with null

Tags: loops, pyspark, replace, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean my dataset from missing values.
In the rows there are values like

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 324 |
| 2 | Breda |  |
| 3 | null | 34556 |

I would like to see in A1 and B2 null and so on without doing the cleaning column by column. I would like to loop over each columns without specifying the column names

I have found this code but the last raw returns an error :
My table name is custom

```
def replaceEmptyCols(columns:Array[String]):Array[Column]={
    columns.map(c>={
      when(col(c)=="" ,null).otherwise(col(c)).alias(c)
    })
  }
custom.select(replaceEmptyCols(custom.columns):_*).show()
```

The error is :

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 6)
  File "<command-447346330485202>", line 6
    custom.select(replaceEmptyCols(custom.columns):_*).show()
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are all your columns of string type? What is the output of `df.printSchema()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?

```
custom = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('1','','324')
    ,('2','Breda','')
    ,('3',None,'34556')
    ],
    ['ID','A','B']
)

custom.show()

# +---+-----+-----+
# | ID|    A|    B|
# +---+-----+-----+
# |  1|     |  324|
# |  2|Breda|     |
# |  3| null|34556|
# +---+-----+-----+

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *


def replaceEmptyCols(df, columns:[]):
    for c in columns:
        df = df.withColumn(c, F.when((F.col(c) == '')  | (F.col(c) == None), F.lit('null')
                                    ).otherwise(F.col(c)))
    return df

replaceEmptyCols(custom, [c for c in custom.columns if c not in ['ID']]).show()
        
# +---+-----+-----+
# | ID|    A|    B|
# +---+-----+-----+
# |  1| null|  324|
# |  2|Breda| null|
# |  3| null|34556|
# +---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I am almost looking for this, only one thing the replace function, i do not want declare the column names because i do not know them (I am pivoting from row values hence i do not know how many columns i will end up and the names of the columns. So this part of the code I have difficulty with : custom.select(replaceEmptyCols(custom.columns):_*).show()

Comment: Updated the answer to make it dynamic. If it fits you please mark as an answer